# Correctly define constraint for UITableViewCell resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm currently facing this problem, i need to define a dynamic height UITableViewCell.

[image]

The red lines correspond to resizable views (will grow vertically), the blue label have 3 constraints: two for each immediate red views above (>= 8), one more with 170 and lower priority to superview.

The green one has a bottom constraint to the superview (5)

When i try to run my code, it gives me this:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19d65bb0 V:[UIView:0x19d9a9a0(5)]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19d667d0 V:[UILabel:0x19de4180(19)]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19d5ba70 V:[UILabel:0x19d61870(19)]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19d36df0 V:[UILabel:0x19d36e80(19)]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19d35d30 V:[UIView:0x19d36130(0)]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19e7b310 V:|-(5)-[UILabel:0x19d6b520]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x19d97580 )>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17d0b060 V:[UILabel:0x19d6b520]-(5)-[UIView:0x19d9a9a0]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17d0a480 V:[UIView:0x19d9a9a0]-(8)-[UILabel:0x19de4180]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17d0c920 V:[UILabel:0x19de4180]-(8)-[UILabel:0x19d61870]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17d0a100 V:[UILabel:0x19d61870]-(8)-[UIView:0x19d839e0]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17d11ad0 V:[UIView:0x19d839e0]-(8)-[UILabel:0x19d36e80]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19e742a0 V:[UILabel:0x19d36e80]-(8)-[UILabel:0x19d36770]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19ed84a0 V:[UILabel:0x19d36770]-(8)-[UIView:0x19d36130]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19e76410 V:[UIView:0x19d36130]-(>=8)-[UILabel:0x19d35560]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19ed8af0 V:[UILabel:0x19d35560]-(8)-[UITextView:0x1832ba00]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19e7abf0 V:[UITextView:0x1832ba00]-(8)-[UILabel:0x19e7d890]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19e83d90 V:[UILabel:0x19e7d890]-(8)-[UITextView:0x18a95e00]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19e7b520 V:[UITextView:0x18a95e00]-(5)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x19d97580 )>",
 "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x19d46fc0 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x19d97580(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x19d36df0 V:[UILabel:0x19d36e80(19)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

So, the question is:
What is the correct way of achieving this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u using `storyboard`, if yes, simple go to `Editor->Resolve Auto Layout Issues->Clear All Constraints In ........ Controller`, and then `Add Missing Constraints In ...... Controller`

It will help you fix the problem of breaking contrainsts between view

Comment: Thsnks, but the issue is how to get [UIView sizeToFit] or [UIView.frame] to reflect the minimum size the view has to contain the expanded views